# Proprietary/Paid for Languages/Compilers

Tags: discussion

I am pretty new here and there is an aspect of the accepted rules that I am not really clear about and would appreciate your opinions.

I have recently posted a few answers using IBM/Lotus Notes Formula Language. The main reason for this is that it interests me in the same way as the Sinclair Spectrum does. Having read through the rules (again) recently I have see that languages/compilers that are not openly available to all members of the community are at the very least discouraged.

My question is twofold.

1. Should I not post using this language? I have noticed that other posters are posting solutions using various Microsoft products including Excel and Powershell which are also proprietary and so thought it would be OK.
2. If I do post with LNFL should I specify it as non-competing, mention that it is written in a not freely available language (for anyone who doesn't know) or just post it "as is".

To be honest, LNFL is very unlikely to win any golf challenges (although I did manage a 2 byte answer for one but was beaten by a byte :-)) and the main reason for posting them is just for the challenge of doing it and seeing another language on the list.

btw, I am not a "one trick pony". I have also got upvotes for a couple of Python answers.

Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: Note that Mathematica is not free but is used widely on PPCG :)

Comment: @BetaDecay Or MATLAB/LabVIEW/BBC BASIC/etc.

Comment: @Erik BBC BASIC is free to a certain extent, so I wouldn't include that

Comment: @BetaDecay It's not free, it simply has a free trial. Also, why is everyone starting to call me `@Erik`? I don't want codegolf on my name, please (except for really long comments).

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't trying to start an argument about what is free and what is not. I was just trying to clarify my position as someone who posts sometimes in a paid-for language. I think @Dennis has answered that. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @BetaDecay It actually *is* free now. [Wolfram Programming Lab](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/) - click "Create a New Notebook" at the bottom.

Comment: @ElPedro I understand, that, I was just correcting Erik so that future users will know some examples of paid-for languages

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you're talking about [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7212/12012):

> ## Using a non-free language on a Cops and Robbers challenge
>
> [...]
>
> An important implicit condition of such a challenge is that it is possible for the robbers to try out many variants of the code to find the true solution. While a cop submission where this is impossible would ostensibly do well, it is not in the spirit of the challenge, and is in fact a loophole.
>
> Therefore, pay-for-use languages are banned as a loophole.

This prohibition only applies to [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenges, where it is important that the robbers have access to the same tools the cop uses.

In all other kinds of challenges, such as plain [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), there is no such requirement, and you're free to use any proprietary/paid-for language you like.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I guess that clarifies it. I was thinking that the rule applied to all challenges. Guess I was @False :-)